# python-social-auth and impersonate django user

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I want to avoid store personal information in database (no last names, no email). This is my approach to achieve it:

1. Delegate authentication to social networks authentication service ( thanks to [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) )
2. Change python-social-auth pipeline to anonymize personal information.

Then I replaced `social_details` step on pipeline by this one:

```
#myapp/mypipeline.py
def social_details(strategy, response, *args, **kwargs):
    import md5
    details = strategy.backend.get_user_details(response)
    email = details['email']
    fakemail = unicode( md5.new(email).hexdigest() )
    new_details = {
                'username': fakemail[:5],
                'email': fakemail + '@noreply.com',
                'fullname': fakemail[:5],
                'first_name': details['first_name'],
                'last_name': '' }
    return {'details': new_details }
```

settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'myapp.mypipeline.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    ...
```

The question:

**Is this the right way to get my purpose?**

Comment: The approach is good and fits the purpose of the pipeline in the application.

Comment: @omab, thanks about your answer and, also, about your great [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) software. Would you like to post comment as an answer in order to check it as solution?

Answer (score -1):

Looks good.

I'm doing something similar to anonymize IP addresses (hash them).

Comment: Looks good? That means that you knows social auth internals and you agree this approach?